# How to convert list element to string?

Tags: c++

I have a try to binding data to textblock in vs 2013.

But I got some problem when I am try to convert list item to string.

this is the error message from vs :

```
no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits,
_Alloc>::basic_string [with _Elem=wchar_t,
_Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>, _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>]"
matches the argument list argument types are:
(std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::string>>>)
```

this is my code :

```
list <string> c1;

//Insert Data
c1.push_back("one");
c1.push_back("two");
c1.push_back("three");
c1.push_back("Four");
c1.push_back("Five");
c1.push_back("Six");
c1.push_back("Seven");
c1.push_back("Eight");
c1.push_back("Nine");
c1.push_back("Ten");




//Random data from list

int RandNum = 0 + (std::rand() % 10);

auto en = c1.begin();
advance(c1.begin(), RandNum);

std::wstring s1(*en);

std::string s2(*en);

ENTEXT->Text = s2; //ENTEXT is textblock name
```

I am try to pass list element to textblock, but this code shows

error C2664 : 'void Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock::Text::set(Platform::String ^)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'Platform::String ^'

Comment: Please provide a working code sample or at least more information. For example what is `cn`?

Comment: The error looks pretty clear. You can't make a string from a single list iterator. Advancing `c1.begin()` should not compile.

Comment: std::wstring is useless, avoid it

Comment: I think you actually want a vector here.

Comment: Hi I already update my code..thankyou

Comment: You need to convert the `std::string` to a `Platform::String` first before setting it to the textblock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're using the wrong variable: `en` is the iterator.
2. You need to **dereference** the iterator: `*en`
3. You accidentally made it a `wstring`.

Here's what it should be:

```
std::string s2(*en);
```

Btw the list elements are already strings, you don't need to convert anything.

To convert a `std::string` to `Platform::String`, you need to use the the `c_str` member function:

```
ENTEXT->Text = en->c_str();
```

Comment: Actually I am try to pass list element to textblock

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote

> "I got some problem when I am try to convert list item to string"

and not specifically `wstring`, I suppose you meant to dereference the right iterator and have `s2` as a normal `std::string` copy

```
int RandNum = 0 + (std::rand() % 10);

auto en = c1.begin();
std::advance(en, RandNum); // Make sure to advance the right iterator

std::string s2(*en);
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f98c4c3ac96abd86)</kbd>

Notice that the above will create a copy of the list element the iterator points to, which, however, is already a `std::string` (no conversion is needed). You could just use the dereferenced iterator:

```
std::cout << *en;
```

In case you really meant the `string->wstring` conversion (for whatever reason not explained in the question), you could write:

```
int RandNum = 0 + (std::rand() % 10);

auto en = c1.begin();
std::advance(en, RandNum); // ditto

std::wstringstream ws;
ws << en->c_str();
std::wstring s2 = ws.str();
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df2c55a720c0f0f8)</kbd>

or, C++11 solution (mind the `-stdlib=libc++` support):

```
//Random data from list

int RandNum = 0 + (std::rand() % 10);

auto en = c1.begin();
advance(en, RandNum);

typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> convert_type;
std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;
std::wstring converted_str = converter.from_bytes(*en);
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/221b5edcf64d7992)</kbd>